# Integrate APICTL commands on IntegrationStudio Sequence

Tags: wso2, api-manager, wso2-integration-studio

I was trying to make some Rest - Service, following the concept of APIctl, and I was wondering if i can integrate the APIctl commands in a sequence on IntegrationStudio.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to achieve using the APICTL commands? The APICTL uses the APIM REST APIs to perform the operations. Since you are trying to create a REST service, you can have a look into the existing [APIM REST APIs](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/develop/product-apis/admin-apis/admin-v1/admin-v1/#tag/API-(Individual)) to achieve your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

In the background, the APICTL uses the APIM REST APIs to perform the operations. Hence, if you are trying to build and expose a new REST-based service to the end-users, you can try integrating the APIM REST APIs to achieve your tasks.

You can refer to the following REST API documentations to get more ideas.

- [APIM Admin REST API](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/develop/product-apis/admin-apis/admin-v1/admin-v1/#tag/API-(Individual))